# How do I use notHasClass to add a Rel= Attribute to a link?

Tags: jquery

I want to add a rel="gallery" to all anchor tags that do not have **class="hidden"**.

Here is what I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (!$('a').hasClass('hidden')) {
    $('a.fancybox').attr('rel', 'gallery1');
});
```

It doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: I believe you forgot to put `}` for your if statement..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is the attribute `rel="gallery1"` all non hidden `fancybox` anchors, then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.fancybox').not('.hidden').attr('rel', 'gallery1');
});
```

Your code will only add the attribute `rel="gallery1"` to all `a.fancybox` elements in the page if non of the `anchor` elements in the page has the `hidden` class.

Comment: Hi Arun, I like your answer best of all because I think it is closest to the ideal of what I am trying to achieve. I applied it here http://dev.rouviere.com/photo/portfolio however you will see if you filter the images that the rel="gallery1" is still applied to all a.fancybox elements even the ones that have .hidden. What do you think? Thank you!

Comment: @fmz in the said page I'm not seeing any `a.fancybox` which has the hidden class

Comment: @fmz when is that class added

Comment: When you click on any of the category filters to filter and sort the images.

Comment: @fmz in that case once you add the class `hidden` you need to remove the `rel` attribute...

Comment: The class hidden is added automatically when you click on the filter. Anything that does not have the filtered class is hidden. How do I remove the rel attribute, because it should only be added to those anchor tags that do not have class of hidden?

Comment: @fmz The problem is the above code is added in dom ready... which runs before the filter... so we need to run the code `$('a.fancybox.hidden').removeAttr('rel'); $('a.fancybox').not('.hidden').attr('rel', 'gallery1');` after the filter

Comment: Your comment makes sense, but I am not sure how to implement it.

Comment: @fmz you have written the filter method right... then why can't you just add these lines at the end of the filter method

Comment: @fmz I think you are doing the filter at [masonry.custom.js](http://dev.rouviere.com/resources/js/masonry.custom.js) in the handler `$('ul#filters a').click()` so add the above said lines at the end of that event handler

Comment: Brilliant. That works perfectly! Thank you for sticking with me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the generalised answer would be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').each(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('hidden')){
            $(this).prop('rel', 'gallery1');
        }
    });
});
```

Note: I assume you have more than 1 anchor..

Answer (score 0):

If you want 'gallery', then use 'gallery', not 'gallery1'

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').each(function() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('hidden')){
            $(this).prop('rel', 'gallery');
        }  
    }
});
```

Also, use prop instead of attr

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").not(".hidden").attr("rel", "gallery");
})
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/ntg55nos/